# Java program wont react till the window gets resized

Tags: java, layout, jbutton

I have a simple java program and when I run it, using eclipse, it displays the 3 JButtons that I have set to the layout. The buttons are set to change the alignment of the layout. So you press left to align left and right to align right and center to align center.

While the buttons do this, the alignment doesn't change in the window till you resize it.

Ive tried updating both the jdk and eclipse and didnt make a difference and I cant see a problem with the code itself.

Anyone know why this is?

import javax.swing.JFrame;

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String []args){

        Layout_buttonsAndActionEvents layout = new Layout_buttonsAndActionEvents();

        layout.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        layout.setSize(300,300);
        layout.setVisible(true);



    }

}



import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

import javax.swing.*;

public class Layout_buttonsAndActionEvents extends JFrame {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private JButton leftButton;
    private JButton rightButton;
    private JButton centerButton;

    private FlowLayout layout;
    private Container container;

    public Layout_buttonsAndActionEvents(){
        super("The Title");
        layout = new FlowLayout();
        container = new Container();
        setLayout(layout);


        leftButton = new JButton("Left");
        add(leftButton);
    //Align to the left
        leftButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){

            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event){
                layout.setAlignment(FlowLayout.LEFT);
                layout.layoutContainer(container);
            }
        });


    centerButton = new JButton("Center");
    add(centerButton);

    //Align to the right
         centerButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){

                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event){
                    layout.setAlignment(FlowLayout.CENTER);
                    layout.layoutContainer(container);
                }
            });

         rightButton = new JButton("Right");
        add(rightButton);

        //Align to the right
            rightButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){

                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event){
                    layout.setAlignment(FlowLayout.RIGHT);
                    layout.layoutContainer(container);
                }
            });



    }


}
```

Comment: do you repack the window after changing the alignment?

Comment: Could you post your code?

Comment: Not in the comments, please. You can edit your question and add it there.

Comment: Sorry first time asking anything on stack

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you are adding the buttons to the JFrame's content
pane ( via the add() method which is really a call to
getContentPane().add() under the covers ) you need to call revalidate() on 
the content pane.

In the three action listeners, change:

```
    layout.setAlignment(FlowLayout.XXX);
    layout.layoutContainer(container);
```

to:

```
    layout.setAlignment(FlowLayout.XXX);
    getContentPane().revalidate();
```

Also, you can remove all references to the variable named 'container' as it does nothing in your example.

Comment: Thank you, this fixed it

Answer (score 0):

When you resize a `JFrame`, it is re-validated with the new size and layout. Similarly, you must validate the and repaint the frame after adding the altered layout to apply a visual difference.

Make sure to call these methods in this order after altering the layout:

```
setLayout(layout);
repaint();
revalidate();
```

Comment: And this gets added in the main or layout class?

Comment: @Yzma it will go in the action listener. Make sure to replace "frame" with the name of your `JFrame` object.

Comment: Its still only changing the alignment after the window is resized, im sure Ive changed it to what you said to do